# RegexValidator to validate emails, making standard attribute

Tags: c#, email, attributes

I would like to validate an email using the RegexValidator, e.g.

```
[RegexValidator(@"^[a-zA-Z][\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]@[a-zA-Z0-9][\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\.]*[a-zA-Z]$")]
```

Which works fine, now I want to wrap the attribute so I can store this in one place:

```
public class EmailAttribute : RegexValidator 
{
    public EmailAttribute()
        : base(@"^[a-zA-Z][\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]@[a-zA-Z0-9][\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\.]*[a-zA-Z]$")
    {
    }
}
```

So I can use

```
[EMail]
```

But it is not working, why?

Comment: What's not working? The attribute or the expression?

Comment: Your regex looks a little short! ;-) http://code.iamcal.com/php/rfc822/full_regexp.txt

Comment: What namespace is RegexValidator in?

Comment: You need a lowercase `M`.  Also, you need to inherit `RegexValidator` **`Attribute`**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should not validate email addresses using regular expressions.

Instead, use this attribute:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false)]
public sealed class EmailAddressAttribute : DataTypeAttribute {
    public EmailAddressAttribute() : base(DataType.EmailAddress) { ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid email address"; }

    public override bool IsValid(object value) {
        if (value == null) return true;
        MailAddress address;
        try {
            address = new MailAddress(value.ToString());
        } catch (FormatException) { return false; }
        return address.Host.IndexOf('.') > 0;    //Email address domain names do not need a ., but in practice, they do.
    }
}
```

If you want client-side validation for ASP.Net MVC, use this adapter:

```
public class EmailAddressValidator : DataAnnotationsModelValidator<EmailAddressAttribute> {
    public EmailAddressValidator(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context, EmailAddressAttribute attribute) : base(metadata, context, attribute) { }

    public override IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules() {
        yield return new ModelClientValidationRegexRule(Attribute.ErrorMessage, 
                     @".+@.+\..+");    //Feel free to use a bigger regex
    }
}
```

And register it like this:

```
DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter(typeof(EmailAddressAttribute), typeof(EmailAddressValidator));
```